# fontawesome icon not appear in place holder

Tags: html

in my code below i'm trying to use an icon in placeholder but it's not appearing , is there a way to solve this?

[image]

```css
input.empty {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <input
                  class="form-control empty" 
                  v-model="login.password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  minlength="6"
                  placeholder="&#xF002;"
                  required
                />
```

Comment: It works for me on Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome also :\ .

Comment: Does this work for you (works for me) - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GN1F7251CMH2?

Comment: It didn't work for me until I linked to the font awesome stylesheet. Try adding:
`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Comment: no it's showing me a square :\ @Endothermic_Dragon

Comment: It's not working in Opera.

Comment: it works here [link](http://example.com)

Comment: What version of FontAwesome are you usign?

Comment: I just realized that the icon is available in v4.5 but not in the latest. It's working with that version. Anyway, are you sure that's what you want to do? I would place another element (`<span class="fa fa-search"></span>` or whatever) over the field with absolute positioning, negative margin, etc. Also make sure that `form-control` isn't causing the issue when you load it along with Bootstrap.

Comment: I would make sure that I've linked to the font awesome stylesheet without which it won't work!

Comment: Note: HTML does not use and does not need or require a closing slash on any tag and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

### FontAwesome 5

Uses the `font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free;`

```css
input {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input
    class="form-control empty" 
    v-model="login.password"
    label="Password"
    type="password"
    minlength="6"
    placeholder="&#xF002;"
    required
/>
```

### FontAwesome 4

Uses the `font-family: FontAwesome;`

```css
input {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input
    class="form-control empty" 
    v-model="login.password"
    label="Password"
    type="password"
    minlength="6"
    placeholder="&#xF002;"
    required
/>
```

Comment: still not working... i'm using Vue js so i added the css link inside my index.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, under the head tag add this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

HTML should be the same but add one more class

```
               <input
                  class="form-control empty fas" 
                  v-model="login.password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  minlength="6"
                  placeholder="&#xF002"
                  required
                />
```

and the CSS ( if required)

```
input.empty {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Comment: still not working... i'm using Vue js so i added the css link inside my index.html

Comment: @Aliessa please check this I tried in codepen.io and found it working

[Sample code](https://codepen.io/mrkd007/pen/vYXqQBW)

Comment: idk why it's still showing me the same &#xF002; in the field, i think it's because of Vue js cuz without semicolon application not working and when i added it it shows field  &#xF002;